# Helping with partitioning a hard drive

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-management

I'm starting to use Windows 8. I have only one partition on my hard drive. And I want to create two individual partitions. But I don't have much experience in partitioning disk. When opening Windows 8 Disk Management I saw a rather strange for me to picture:

[image: partitions]

I don't understand what all of these sections mean and what should I do with them. I want to create only two discs: `С`(with OS) and `D`(media files). Please tell me how do I correctly solve my problem? Can I safely remove the other sections? Which of them must I leave intact?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a name brand PC? Also, why not just extend C: into the unallocated space? Partitions seem limiting to me.

Comment: A larger screenshot (to imgur preferably!) would be very nice.

Comment: You need to pay attention to the sizes of these partitions.  The first two are only 499MB and 300MB.  The pictorial representation of these partitions do not have accurate relative sizes.  Just use that **unallocated** region of 195GB for your new partition for **D:**.

Comment: No matter what you do, I would strongly suggest you make a full disk backup using Clonezilla or similar tools.

Answer (score 2):

I would NOT touch any of the partitions except the one labelled "unallocated", as the others were probably set up by Windows during install. You especially do NOT want to touch the EFI partition, as that is required for your system to boot.

However, the unallocated partition has nothing on it, so it is safe to make a D: in that free space if you so wish.

I must add, however, I have no idea what the recovery partitions are doing that the end of the drive like that. I don't have much experience with Windows 8, but I've never quite seen a partition setup like that.

Comment: Unfortunately I can shrink disk `C` only to 338 GB. I think this is due to the fact that these additional sector took up too much unjustified space.

Comment: Is there a reason you need separate partitions? It does seem to make more sense to just expand C: into the unallocated space.

Comment: Yes, I want to have two different partitions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! But unfortunately I still don't know how I can allocate at least 500 GB drive `D`. I wouldn't want to install special additional soft to resolve this problem.

Comment: Assuming you can't free up space on C:, it's not possible to have a 500GB D: if you can't make C: smaller than 338 GB. Your drive just isn't big enough.